# Inner text messing up layout of inline-block list items

Tags: html, css

I've created a jsfiddle of this here so you can see what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/QcRvz/1/

Basically, I have an unordered list, with the list items displaying as inline-block:

```
<ul id="folders">
    <li></li>
    <li><span>Test</span></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

For some reason, if I enter text or anything inside the list items, it messes up the top margin of that list item.

Can anyone see what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `vertical-align` to `top` (or `bottom` etc.):

```
ul#folders li
{
    /* ... */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QcRvz/2/

The default is `baseline` which aligns the baseline of the text instead of the boxes themselves if there is any text.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your CSS rules for the list items.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QcRvz/3/)**

The default vertical-align value is baseline, however you want top instead so they align properly.

Answer (score 1):

[See this jsFiddle (updated from your link)](http://jsfiddle.net/QcRvz/4/)

You just need to add `vertical-align:top;` to the `li`'s